# How to change ring and text color by using SVProgressHUDStyleCustom

Tags: ios, objective-c, svprogresshud

I want to show both Ring and Text color of Hud differently.I'm using hud style `SVProgressHUDStyleCustom`, but unable to achieve the desired result.

**My code is following:**

```
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultStyle:SVProgressHUDStyleCustom];
[SVProgressHUD setRingThickness:5.0];
[SVProgressHUD setForegroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[SVProgressHUD setFont:[UIFont ProximaNovaA_Light:16.0]];
[SVProgressHUD setCornerRadius:3];
[SVProgressHUD setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudForegroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:16]];
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudStatusShadowColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Great Success!"];
```

Comment: This code is not working with the latest SVProgressHud.